# Nashorn: Call function inside of a namespace

Tags: javascript, java, namespaces, nashorn

I have evaluated the following script using the `NashornScriptEngine`:

```
var Namespace = {
    test: function()
    {
        return "It works";
    }
}
```

**Now I want to call the function `test`.**

When using the method `invokeFunction` of the nashorn engine, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such function Namespace.test
```

How is it possible to call this function?

Comment: Could you include the java source code also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to access a global function called `window["Namespace.test"]`, not `window.Namespace.Test`. You first need to get a reference to `Namespace`, then you can call [`invocable.invokeMethod`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/Invocable.html#invokeMethod-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) specifying `Namespace` as its context (`this`).

For example, to call `JSON.parse()`, you can use the following:

```
Object json = engine.eval("JSON"); // Or "Namespace" in your case
Object data = invocable.invokeMethod(json, "parse", contactJson); //"test" for the case you mention
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. By the way, from your variable namings I guess that you called the method `invokeMethod` on an `Invocable` object. Is it always safe to cast `engineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn")` to `NashornScriptEngine`?

Comment: @Ercksen I am not 100% sure, but the following code is safe `ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn"); Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine; inv.invokeFunction("hello", "Scripting!");` If you have further questions, please ask a separate question so it can be useful to other users of SO

Comment: It would be great if you could include the whole solution.  If the javascript code (var Namespace={....}) is in a string called say js, then you would have to do "engine.eval(js)" or "engine.eval(reader)" if you are using a file reader.  I dont see how you can eval a string literal "JSON" or "Namespace" as this is not javascript code.  Contexts are not really explained in the reference docs, and havent found any useful descriptions of what they are and how to use them

Comment: @johnlittle the example I provided works. JSON is a built-in namespace, it is a valid JS reference. I'm showing you how to call its parseString method. If the OP had already created a global called Namespace, by evaling it previously, you can access that also from the same engine