# Nashorn: how to invoke a function on a function or object

Tags: nashorn

One of the recommended ways to write javascript modules is like this:

```
var engine = (function() {
    // private stuff goes here...
    function composeGreeting() {return 'Hello';};
    return {
       composeGreeting: composeGreeting
    } // return
})();
```

However, if you eval the above file using nashorn, I cant find a way to invoke "composeGreeting"

The file is evaluated like this:

```
File file = new File("my.js")
Reader reader = file.newReader();
engine.eval(reader)
Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
```

I tried calling the function like this:

```
Object funcResult = invocable.invokeFunction("engine.composeGreeting");
```

But this does not work.

I also took a stab in the dark and tried this:

```
 funcResult = invocable.invokeMethod(engine.get("engine"), "composeGreeting");
```

However, this gives the error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException"

Tried this also (doesnt work)

```
funcResult = invocable.invokeFunction("engine").invokeFunction("composeGreeting");
```

Tried this also (renderServer is null)

```
ScriptObjectMirror renderServer = (ScriptObjectMirror) scriptEngine.get("engine");
```

funcResult = renderServer.call("composeGreeting");

Any suggestions?  The documentation says that get just returns an object - there is no mention of what the object actually is or how to use it.

Obviously, if my js file just had this:

```
function composeGreeting() {return 'Hello';};
```

and nothing more, I can happily call it like this:

```
Object funcResult = invocable.invokeFunction("composeGreeting");
```

But this will expose all the private inner gubbins of my js file.

To be honest, I dont know what the type of "engine" will be.

Note: we cant use graalVM as graalVM only supports java 8 out of the box currently, and there are even fewer examples for GraalVM than nashorn.

This post hints it is possible, but does not include the solution:
[Nashorn: Call function inside of a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082818/nashorn-call-function-inside-of-a-namespace)

Answer (score 0):

I was on the right track.  A working answer was posted [here](https://devhobbs.wordpress.com/2019/10/10/nashorn-using-javascript-modules-from-java-groovy/).

The crux is this line:

```
funcResult = invocable.invokeMethod(scriptEngine.get("engine"), "composeGreeting");
```

Not sure why this didn't work for me before, but it's working now.